# ADB command from macOS application with special characters

Tags: android, swift, macos, shell, adb

I want to pull a file from my android device through an `adb` command from my macOS application.

Everything works perfect with the code below, except when the name of the file I want to pull contains special characters like german umlauts (äöüÄÖÜ).

I get this error:
`adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse': No such file or directory`.

But when I use the command `adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse ~/Desktop` from within the `Terminal.app`, the file will be pulled to my computer.

The strange thing here is that if I copy the substring `/storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse` from the Xcode console output, the command is also not working within the `Terminal.app` until I delete the `ö` and replace it with an `ö` from my keyboard input.

I tried replacing the `ö` with the unicode representation `\u{00f6}`, but this has no effect (but the console output still shows an `ö` but the 'wrong' encoded one.

```
// Configure task.
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"
task.arguments = ["pull", "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse", "~/Desktop"]

// Configure pipe.
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
task.launch()

// Run task.
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
task.waitUntilExit()

// adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse': No such file or directory
print(output)
```

I found the following in the documentation, how the `Process` handles the arguments that I provide:

> The NSTask object converts both path and the strings in arguments to appropriate C-style strings (using fileSystemRepresentation) before passing them to the task via argv[] . The strings in arguments do not undergo shell expansion, so you do not need to do special quoting, and shell variables, such as $PWD, are not resolved.

It seems like I am not the only one with this problem, and I found this workaround:
[How to work around NSTask calling -[NSString fileSystemRepresentation] for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459711/how-to-work-around-nstask-calling-nsstring-filesystemrepresentation-for-argum), but I was not able to make it work with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I am now writing my adb command to a file and execute it from a bash command in my application.

```
let source = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Böse"
let destination = "~/Desktop"
guard let uniqueURL = URL(string: destination + "/" + ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString) else { return }

// Write command to file
let scriptContent = "#!/bin/bash\n~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb pull -a \"" + source + "\" \"" + destination + "\""
try? scriptContent.write(to: uniqueURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

// Configure task.
let task = Process()
task.environment = ["LC_ALL": "de_DE.UTF-8", "LANG": "de_DE.UTF-8"]
task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
task.arguments = [uniqueURL.path]

// Configure pipe.
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
try? task.run()

// Run task.
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
task.waitUntilExit()

print(output)
```

Even though this is working for now, it is not a satisfactory solution as it is not very elegant and not efficient too, so any improvements or better answers are welcome.