# Swift URL.path changes encoding of utf-8 characters

Tags: ios, swift, macos, encoding, utf-8

Why does converting a `String` to an `URL` in Swift 4.2 and then converting the `URL` back to a `String` using `url.path` change the encoding of special characters like german umlauts (ä, ö, ü), even if I use a utf-8 encoding?

I wrote some sample code to show my problem. I encoded the strings to base64 in order to show that there is a difference.

I also have a similar unsolved problem with special characters and swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049738/adb-command-from-macos-application-with-special-characters).

## Sample Code

```
let string = "/path/to/file"
let stringUmlauts = "/path/to/file/with/umlauts/testäöü"

let base64 = Data(string.utf8).base64EncodedString()
let base64Umlauts = Data(stringUmlauts.utf8).base64EncodedString()

print(base64, base64Umlauts)

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: string)
let urlUmlauts = URL(fileURLWithPath: stringUmlauts)

let base64Url = Data(url.path.utf8).base64EncodedString()
let base64UrlUmlauts = Data(urlUmlauts.path.utf8).base64EncodedString()

print(base64Url, base64UrlUmlauts)
```

## Output

The `base64` and `base64Url` string stay the same but the `base64Umlauts` and the `base64UrlUmlauts` are different.

> "L3BhdGgvdG8vZmlsZQ==" for `base64`
>
> "L3BhdGgvdG8vZmlsZQ==" for `base64Url`
>
> "L3BhdGgvdG8vZmlsZS93aXRoL3VtbGF1dHMvdGVzdMOkw7bDvA==" for `base64Umlauts`
>
> "L3BhdGgvdG8vZmlsZS93aXRoL3VtbGF1dHMvdGVzdGHMiG/MiHXMiA==" for `base64UrlUmlauts`

When I put the `base64Umlauts` and `base64UrlUmlauts` strings into an online Base64 decoder, they both show `/path/to/file/with/umlauts/testäöü`, but the `ä, ö, ü` are different (not visually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringUmlauts.utf8` uses the Unicode characters `äöü`.

But `urlUmlauts.path.utf8` uses the Unicode characters `aou` each followed by the combining `¨`.

This is why you get different base64 encoding - the characters look the same but are actually encoded differently.

What's really interesting is that `Array(stringUmlauts)` and `Array(urlUmlauts.path)` are the same. The difference doesn't appear until you perform the UTF-8 encoding of the otherwise exact same `String` values.

Since the base64 encoding is irrelevant, here's a more concise test:

```
let stringUmlauts = "/path/to/file/with/umlauts/testäöü"
let urlUmlauts = URL(fileURLWithPath: stringUmlauts)

print(stringUmlauts, urlUmlauts.path) // Show the same

let rawStr = stringUmlauts
let urlStr = urlUmlauts.path

print(rawStr == urlStr) // true
print(Array(rawStr) == Array(urlStr)) // true
print(Array(rawStr.utf8) == Array(urlStr.utf8)) // false!!!
```

So how is the UTF-8 encoding of two equal strings different?

One solution to this is to use `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` on the result of `path`.

```
let urlStr = urlUmlauts.path.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
```

Now you get `true` from:

```
print(Array(rawStr.utf8) == Array(urlStr.utf8)) // now true
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works! But when I pass this `String` as an argument to a `Process`, then the `NSTask` seems to convert it under the hood to the wrong encoding (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049738/adb-command-from-macos-application-with-special-characters)). Do you how I can fix the problem there?