# Swift String (With Diacritics) Isn't Passing Into CLI Process Correctly

Tags: swift, string, command-line-interface, formal-languages

This bug/issue has been bugging me for many months. I've sunk hours trying to solve it. Any help/direction is super welcome!

---

When trying to run the following function it **always** throws an error when using certain diacritics (ä, etc.)

My end goal: Allow any language's special characters to be passed into the CLI interface.

```swift
func runShortcut(inputShortcut: String) {
    let shortcutsCLI = Process()
    shortcutsCLI.standardInput = nil //TODO: DTS Fix. This allows us to run the Shortcut!!!
    
    shortcutsCLI.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/shortcuts")
    shortcutsCLI.arguments = ["run", inputShortcut.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] //decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping / composed
    print("Full args: ", shortcutsCLI.arguments) //Prints: Optional(["run", "ä"])
    
    do {
        try shortcutsCLI.run()
        print("Should've ran the shortcut...")
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

runShortcut(inputShortcut: "ä")
```

I've tried forming the input "string" as Unicode `let str = "\u{00c4}"`, formed from binary, etc. Doesn't seem to matter how I get to the character/string "ä", it refuses to work.

I've also tried `str.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` & `str.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`, both unsuccessful.

Everything works fine, running from the CLI, Python & Go. I strongly believe it has something to do with how the string is being passed into the `Process()`.

With that being said, I'm unsure if it's an issue with the String that's being passed in, or if it's an underlying issue with the `Process()`.

---

I have saved the `inputShortcut` variable to a local .txt file, then using this command `cat "/PathToTxt/a.txt" | xargs shortcuts run`, & that works fine, no matter what characters I throw at it. This makes me believe it's less of an issue with the underlying String.

Comment: What error do you get with the code you posted?

Comment: So you are trying to remove the diacritic marks? That's not what `decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` does.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29521951/5133585)

Comment: @HangarRash the error is: "Error: The requested shortcut was not found", which is the default error from the Shortcuts CLI.

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not trying to remove the diacritic marks. In the case of the example, passing a standard "a" \u{0041}. I want the "ä" \u{00c4}? passed into the function. I can verify that using the standard "a" with the CLI throws the std error.

I know you can combine two or more signs to form the character with diacritics, but my combinations were either unsuccessful or formed wrongly.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The underlying issue seems to be described in the documentation for `Process arguments`: *"converts both path and the strings in arguments to appropriate C-style strings (using fileSystemRepresentation) before passing them to the task through argv[]."*. The string `"ä"` gets turned into `"aÃà"` which is why the shortcut isn't found.

Comment: See [How to work around NSTask calling -NSString fileSystemRepresentation for arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459711/how-to-work-around-nstask-calling-nsstring-filesystemrepresentation-for-argum) for a possible solution (look at the non-Objective-C answer).

Comment: This seems to have pointed me in the right direction. I'm able to process most of the character set that I have, with the exception being spaces. It's seeing them as another argument per space, but that's just some formatting stuff I presume. Thanks for the help, @HangarRash!